# How to have links automatically open the safari app (not locally) in iOS with Xcode/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safari, info.plist

I am working on integrating the Snap SDK into my app and to login with Snapchat, a safari webpage needs to be opened. This is done automatically by the SDK, but this opens safari locally in the app as a popup. I don't want this to happen as at the end of the login process, the page prompts the user to "continue" which if done in the safari app would bring the user back to the app but if done locally does nothing (because the app is already open). This is quite inconvenient as the user might become confused. My code only calls the login, but it is posted below along with a photo of my Info.plist. How can I get it to NOT open locally?

Code:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: self) { success, error in
        if let error = error {
            // An error occurred during the login process
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // The login was a success! This user is now
            // authenticated with Snapchat!
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Info.plist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've imported the following into your ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import SafariServices
```

This will open Safari directly, not a safari popover. It should be said that Apple prefers for the user to not have to leave the app during login, and messing with these mechanics may turn out to cause your app to not be approved.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```